Receiving HHH015007 Illegal argument on static metamodel field injection Error During Quarkus Startup with Hibernate Envers
In learning Quarkus, I encountered an issue during the startup of my YOUR SECOND QUARKUS APPLICATION, which I extended to use Hibernate Envers for auditing. The application shows an IllegalArgumentException error related to static metamodel field injection that I can't figure out. Despite this, Hibernate creates the audit tables, and after performing some transactions, I can see audit data. But I'd like to understand what is causing the error.
Below is the FULL login showing the specific error message:
2024-09-28 07:52:09,012 INFO  [org.hib.env.con.int.met.AuditMetadataGenerator] (Quarkus Main Thread) Adding properties for entity: db.model.Person
2024-09-28 07:52:09,983 ERROR [org.hib.met.int.MetadataContext] (JPA Startup Thread) HHH015007: Illegal argument on static metamodel field injection : org.hibernate.envers.DefaultRevisionEntity_#class_; expected type :  org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.EntityTypeImpl; encountered type : jakarta.persistence.metamodel.MappedSuperclassType
2024-09-28 07:52:10,143 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) getting-started 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT on JVM (powered by Quarkus 3.14.4) started in 6.202s. Listening on: http://localhost:8080
2024-09-28 07:52:10,143 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Profile dev activated. Live Coding activated.
2024-09-28 07:52:10,144 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Installed features: [agroal, cdi, hibernate-envers, hibernate-orm, jdbc-postgresql, narayana-jta, resteasy, resteasy-jsonb, smallrye-context-propagation, vertx]

I initially:
Started using hibernate-orm-panache extension with ActiveRecord pattern. Switched to  Repository pattern to see if the automatic entity @id would be causing the problem.
I switched to the hibernate-orm and added a Sequence generator, but I had no luck.
Here is the Entity definition:

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;

import java.time.LocalDate;

@Entity
@Audited
public class Person {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "personSeq", sequenceName = "person_id_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "personSeq")
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private LocalDate birth;
    private Status status;

    public Long getId(){
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id){
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public LocalDate getBirth() {
        return birth;
    }
    public void setBirth(LocalDate birth) {
        this.birth = birth;
    }
    public Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(Status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}

POM.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.acme</groupId>
    <artifactId>getting-started</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
        <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
        <quarkus.platform.version>3.14.4</quarkus.platform.version>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.11.0</compiler-plugin.version>
        <surefire-plugin.version>3.1.2</surefire-plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-info</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>native</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <quarkus.native.enabled>true</quarkus.native.enabled>
                <quarkus.package.jar.enabled>false</quarkus.package.jar.enabled>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                                        <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>


This looks like a bug in Hibernate Envers: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-17612
